# Firebase increment value works for some time then breaks

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift2, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app to buy/sell used books, each time a book marked as Sold I have this swift code to increment the number of sold books in a Firebase real time database.

```
    bookRef.child(book.bookKey!).child("Sold").setValue(true)
    statisticsRef.child("SoldBooksNumber").observeSingleEventOfType(FIRDataEventType.Value ,withBlock: { (snap) in
        let soldBooksNumber = (snap.value?.intValue)! + 1
        statisticsRef.child("SoldBooksNumber").setValue("\(soldBooksNumber)")
    })
```

bookRef and staticsRef are two references to two nodes in the RTDB.

**The Problem I am having:** This code worked just fine for a while, after some time the value starts to go down from let's say 59 to 22! I was thinking if it was because of two were updating at the same time then it would be 60 instead of 61 or so, But not from 59 to 22!

I wonder if anyone can guess what is the causing problem,

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try:-

```
statisticsRef.runTransactionBlock({ (snap) -> FIRTransactionResult in
    if let valueToBeAppended = snap.value as? Int{
        snap.value = valueToBeAppended + 1
        return FIRTransactionResult.successWithValue(snap)
      }else{
        return FIRTransactionResult.successWithValue(snap)
       }
    }, andCompletionBlock: {(error,completion,snap) in
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
            print(completion)
            print(snap)

              if !completion {
                  print("The value wasn't able to Update")
                 }else{
                  print("Value updated")
                    }
           })
```

Comment: Can you explain why this code will solve the problem I am having? especially the number decreasing it value by a half. Thank you

Comment: `transactionBlocks`  are a workaround the race problems, which i think is happening in your case.